# How to prepare walls after skim coating?

Tags: painting, drywall-mud

Our contractor just finished skim coating drywall/plaster walls. It seems like the walls are still dusty from sanding, etc. what do I need to do to prep the walls for priming/painting?

I obviously need to get rid of the dust. Do I wipe it down and then wait for the walls to dry again? What else do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Damp towel. It picks up the dust, it doesn't really get the wall particularly wet.

Comment: I did this and primed without any problems.